# Access updated FormikProps after arrayHelper function runs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have the following code:

```
  addLineItem = (formProps: FormikProps<MyEntity>, arrayHelpers: ArrayHelpers) => {
    arrayHelpers.push(getNewEntity(formProps.values.date));
    reassignLineItemIds(formProps);
  };
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that `reassignLineItemIds` needs the updated values in `formProps` and I don't have access to the updated version of `formProps` after `arrayHelpers.push()` has run.

One solution I came across involved creating the following component:

```
interface ConnectedProps {
  delay?: number;
  onChange: (prevProps: FormikProps<MyEntity>, nextProps: FormikProps<MyEntity>) => void;
}

interface OwnProps extends ConnectedProps {
  formik: FormikProps<FormikValues>;
}

class FormChangeHandler extends Component<OwnProps> {
  onChange = debounce(this.props.onChange, this.props.delay || 0);

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: OwnProps) {
    const { formik } = this.props;
    const { isValid } = formik;

    const hasChanged = !isEqual(prevProps.formik.values, formik.values);
    const shouldCallback = isValid && hasChanged;

    if (shouldCallback) {
      this.onChange(prevProps.formik as FormikProps<MyEntity>, formik as FormikProps<MyEntity>);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

const connected = connect<ConnectedProps>(FormChangeHandler);

export { connected as FormChangeHandler };
```

Then, in my Formik `<Form>`, include the following:

```
<FormChangeHandler onChange={
    (prevProps: FormikProps<MyEntity>, nextProps: FormikProps<MyEntity>) => {
        if (getLineItemCount(prevProps.values) !== getLineItemCount(nextProps.values)) {
        reassignLineItemIds(nextProps);
    }
}} />
```

This works, but it will have negative performance impacts and just seems like a crazy hoop to jump through.

Comment: There is a [feature request for asynchronous array helpers](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1253), which seems to be the ideal, but sadly impossible solution.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner It's just shocking this isn't available.

Comment: You could hook into validations, as that essentially functions as a state change callback, but because they are named "validations" that feels dirty. But programmatically, that seems your best option for now.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution still seems to be a bit of a hack, and that is to hook into validations. Validations are triggered when (some) array helpers are called, so that mechanism could be used as a callback when state updates. Still not the ideal solution, but it looks like that's the closest available solution at the moment.